# WSO2IS 5.11.0 - Empty screen when loggin to /myconsole or /myaccount

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have an issue when I try to login to WSO2/myaccount or <WSO2IS_URL>/console. I can fill my login and password, but when after to have clic on submit button, I get an empty screen.

It worked the first time after a reboot of my machine.

1. Login & Password -> Submit
2. My personal page appeared
3. Logout
4. Login & Password -> Submit
5. I got an empty screen (blank page)

I have to say that I am behind an NGINX reverse proxy hosted in another machine.

I check in my browser and I get this message:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Invalid id_token in the token response: 
eyJ4NXQiOiJNell4TW1Ga09HWXdNV0kwWldObU5EY3hOR1l3WW1NNFpUQTNNV0kyTkRBe.......
```

I checked my callback URLs for myAccount and Console SP and they are corrects.
I checked also the *"Identity Provider Entity ID"* for *"OAuth2/OpenID Connect Configuration"*, and it is also correct.

Hereunder my deployment.toml file:

```
[server]
hostname = "<MY_WSO2IS_DOMAIN_NAME>"
node_ip = "192.168.xxx.yy1"
base_path = "https://$ref{server.hostname}"
offset = 0
internal_hostname= "identity"

[sts.endpoint] 
idp = "https://$ref{server.hostname}/samlsso"

.../...
```

The "node_ip" value is the one for the NGINX reverse proxy hosted in another machine.

I tried many many things but I don't find where is the issue.

Any idea is welcome and appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/10644 Check this issue

Comment: If that does not work for you kindly add the decoded id token to the issue

Answer (score 1):

Seems your resident identity provider settings still set to localhost. If that is the case you have to change the settings as follows:[image]

finally update changes by clicking the "update" button at the bottom.